# Chartist.js: Shadowing / Outline on mouseover for pie / donut chart

Tags: javascript, svg, chartist.js

I have some donut charts created with Chartist.js and tooltips with tmmdata's plugin (https://github.com/tmmdata/chartist-plugin-tooltip) but there is only one thing I want more from this setup - a visual effect similar to the one Google charts uses (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut) that outlines a mouse overed slice with a fainter shade of that same color.

Does anyone have a good idea for how to accomplish this with Chartist?

Comment: I think this might be done by tweaking when the graph is created, saying use like the .on('draw', function(data){} and duplicate each path within the g element. And then you can move it out with opacity and enable disable it with CSS?

Comment: At least that's how the google one works, it add this piece of code when hovering: <path d="M340,93.25A157.75,157.75,0,0,1,380.82870436492266,403.37479909710055" stroke="#3366cc" stroke-width="6.5" stroke-opacity="0.3" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>

Comment: Hi! Did you ever figure out how to achieve this effect? I'm looking to do the same, and curious to if you found a good solution.

Comment: Sorry; I don't really recall. I haven't seen that code base in a year.